# Is it possible to convert Leads to Contacts with Person Accounts turned on?

Tags: lead-conversion, person-accounts

Is it possible to convert Leads to Contacts with Person Accounts turned on?

We are working on unwinding person accounts and going back to using contacts. We know that person accounts cannot be turned off at this time. We just want to know if we can get around them in the lead conversion process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the Company field required. As long as that field is populated, the system will create normal business accounts and contacts. Person Accounts are only created when the Company field is not filled in.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to change your lead conversion process and make certain you have a record type configured that allows for Contacts that aren't Person Accounts. I.E. Contacts associated with Business Accounts. To do that, you'll probably want to set up a new Opportunity Sales Process. You may need to create a custom lead conversion process. Since I don't know how your org is configured, I can't really say. There's a [lead convert](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_convertLead.htm%23apex_dml_convertLead) class described in the Apex Docs you can use to create your own custom process/page.